# In Java , no TransformerException is thrown while performing XSLT transformation when I send a bad XML ( XML with no tags mentioned in XSLT)

Tags: java, xml, xslt

In Java , while transforming one XML into another XML using an XSLT file , when given a bad XML as input ( negative testing) no TransformerException is thrown.

Bad XML here is an XML with no tags which XSLT expects
Example of Bad XML
123

XSLT snapshot ( Note Sample is not a tag specified anywhere here )

```
 *<xsl:template match="/SammpleReply" xpath-default-namespace="SammpleReply" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
       <RadialReply xmlns="http://SammpleReply.com">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="PaymentContextBase">
                   <PaymentContextBase>
                       <OrderId><xsl:value-of select="RadialReply/Radial:RadialReplySessionId"/></OrderId>
                   </PaymentContextBase>
                   <TenderType><xsl:value-of select="RadialReply/Radial:TenderType"/></TenderType>
                </xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>
                    <RadialReplyContext>
                        <OrderId><xsl:value-of select="RadialContext/payment:RadialUniqueId"/></OrderId>
                         <xsl:element name="RadialUniqueId" >
                            <xsl:attribute name="isToken"><xsl:value-of select="RadialContext/payment:PaymentAccountUniqueId/@isToken"/></xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="RadialContext/payment:RadialUniqueId"/>
                         </xsl:element>
                    </RadialReplyContext>
                   <TenderType><xsl:value-of select="PaymentContext/payment:TenderType"/></TenderType>
               </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <SlotsAvailable><xsl:value-of select="SlotsAvailability"/></SlotsAvailable>
           <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Reattempt">
                    <ReauthorizationAttempted><xsl:value-of select="ReattemptValue"/></ReauthorizationAttempted>
                </xsl:when>
           </xsl:choose>
       </RadialReply>*
```

Input

```
<Sample>202008131228</Sample>
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>202008131228
```

**Desired Result :** If an incoming XML does not have any XML element defined in XSLT . Exception should be thrown ( Which is not happening ) Need to know why and I want the code to throw an exception in this case . What code logic would achieve that ?
Code just loads the XSLT File and transforms it . Code does not go to exception block. it transforms successfully and String outputResultStr  is the output above

```
 Reader xmlReader = new StringReader(payloadStr);
                StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                Result result = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
                transformer.transform(new StreamSource(xmlReader), result);
                outputResultStr = stringWriter.toString();
                

            } catch (TransformerException trEx) {
                  }
```

Comment: The use of `xpath-default-namespace="SammpleReply"` suggests you use Saxon. If that is Saxon 9.8 or later try adding `<xsl:mode on-no-match="fail"/>`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#built-in-templates-fail.

Comment: Any similar solution available for XSLT 2.0 ?

Comment: See the answer by Michael Kay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, add a template rule

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:message terminate="yes">Unknown element <xsl:value-of select="name()"/></xsl:message>
</xsl:template>
```

to match elements that are not matched by any other template rule.

In 3.0, add `<xsl:mode on-no-match="fail"/>`.

The reason it's not failing is that XSLT defines a default template rule to process elements that are not matched by any other template rule in the stylesheet.

Comment: This worked . But also can we error out if the incoming XML has any of the tag missing , as defined in XSLT .  For example ``` <OrderNumber><xsl:value-of select="ContextItem/order:orderID"/></OrderNumber> ``` if we do not have a order id in the xml can we error out ?

Comment: One way to do that is to use a schema-aware XSLT transformation, with the XML validity rules defined separately in XSD.

Answer (score 0):

xsl transform will pass even if there are no matching tags.

There are several options ...

- refactor xsl to match / and look for desired/allowed tags and throw error using `<xsl:message terminate="yes"/>` if not found
- create xml schema for input xml an validate before transform

Comment: In the transformation logic , when it tries to refer the source tag , and the source tag is not found in the XML , is it possible to throw an error in this case ?

Comment: <xsl-if test="whatever"><xsl:message terminate="yes">tag not found</xsl:message></xsl-if>

Comment: "whatever" here refers to the name of the source  tag I believe .

Answer (score 0):

You can implement SAX schema validation API before XSLT transformation.

> Here my SAX validation program specifies the schema to validate XML input data:

```
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

    InputSourceHandle saxHandle = new InputSourceHandle();
    
    saxHandle.setErrorHandler(new InputSourceHandle.DraconianErrorHandler());
            
    String procSchema =
          "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" +
          "<xs:schema xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' " +
              "xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' " +
              "xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema XMLSchema.xsd'>" +
            "<xs:element name='ProcedureDocument'>" +
              "<xs:complexType mixed='true'>" +
                "<xs:choice minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded'>" +
                  "<xs:element name='title'/>" +
                  "<xs:element name='confidentialityCode'/>" +
                  "<xs:element name='originalText'/>" +
                  "<xs:element name='statusCode'/>" +                     
                  "<xs:element name='methodCode'/>" +
                  "<xs:element name='reference'/>" +
                "</xs:choice>" +
                "<xs:attribute name=\"value\" type='xs:string' use='optional'/>" +
              "</xs:complexType>" +
            "</xs:element>" +
          "</xs:schema>";

    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new StringReader(procSchema)));

saxHandle.setDefaultWriteSchema(schema);
…….
//proceed XSLT transformation
```

> A well-formed and valid XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
</ProcedureDocument>
    <title>Procedures Anesthesia</title>
    <confidentialityCode>Confidential</confidentialityCode>
    <originalText>Cardiac Surgery :: CABG, arterial, three</originalText>
    <statusCode code="performed"/>
    <methodCode>UNK</methodCode>
    <reference value="#Procedure2"/>
</ProcedureDocument>
```

Just one validation can precisely catch all range of erroneous input and exit the application gracefully.

> e.g: missing tag `</ProcedureDocument>`

```
Error 
   Error reported by XML parser processing null: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of
  element 'title'.: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'title'.
```

> e.g: ill-formed element/attribute =>  `<reference Value="#Procedure2"/>`

```
Error 
   Error reported by XML parser processing null: The markup in the document preceding the
  root element must be well-formed.: The markup in the document preceding the root element
  must be well-formed.
```

> e.g: ill-formed xpath/tag =>

```
ProcedureDocument
    <title>Procedures Anesthesia</title>
```

```
Error 
   Error reported by XML parser processing null: Content is not allowed in prolog.: Content
  is not allowed in prolog.
```